# My background stopped looping and is mushy and weird looking

Tags: c#, unity

My looping bacground texture looped perfectly, but maybe after building the project as an android project broke it? How can I fix it?

[image: The background]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScrollScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 0.01f;

void Start () {

}

void Update () {
    Vector2 offset = new Vector2 (Time.time * speed, 0);

    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
}
}
```

Comment: perhaps switching the platform messed up the texture setting. Check the compression point filters, mip maps and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps switching the platform messed up the texture setting. Check the compression point filters, mip maps and so on. As suggested I moved my comment to be a answer.

Comment: REMEMBER TO CHANGE YOUR WRAP MODE TO REPEAT!

Answer (score 1):

[GetComponent](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/getcomponent) calls are way to expensive to use in Update like that, especially on mobile, because Update is called once per frame. A main rule of thumb is repeat actions as little as possible, so do things like GetComponent once and store it in a variable.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScrollScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 0.01f;

private Material _material;

void Start () {
_material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
}

void Update () {
    _material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2 (Time.time * speed, 0);
}
}
```

For performance on mobile, even [using material](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html) isn't the best way, but it should work for you until your ready to dive a bit deeper. You may never need to do anything different, but I personally like to use a few sprites and scroll them past in a loop. Think of it like holding up three pictures. Take the last picture and put it in front of the first, while the player can only see the middle one. Continue this as long as needed.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks for the performance tips, but after the loop in the code begins it looks like rings of Saturn again.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad someone thought to tell you to check the import settings weren't different between platforms.